# custom container view controller vs normal segue and rewind segues

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, ios9

My intent was to create a master scene and view controller that was in control most of the time, but when logic demanded it would segue to one of several other scenes.  Each of these "other" scenes would return to the master view controller using rewind segues.  Which other scene was chosen was determined by logic in the master view controller.   This worked fine until I found a need to transition from one of the "other" scenes to a different "other" scene without presenting anything from the master scene.  I want to put a performSegueWithIdentifier in the master view controller before anything is presented.

I have tried putting the performSegue.. in the method that catches the rewind segue, in the viewWillAppear method, in a block kicked off async from the rewind method, but in all cases I see the performSegueWithIdenitifer method execute, then the appropriate prepareForSegue but then control returns to the master view controller and the scene I get in the device is from the master view controller.

I tried to look at other methods and it would seem that building a custom container view controller is one way of doing this, but it does not seem right since all the "other" scenes I want to segue to are push segues and take over the entire screen.

Is there some reason that a view controller that has received control from a rewind segue cannot then kickoff a segue without ever appearing itself?  Is the Custom container view controller the correct way to do this?  And if the latter, do I let the storyboard set up the embed segues to all the other view controllers, or do I leave them unconnected in the storyboard and load them in code?

Thanks in advance, ##warning - novice here -  this is my first real project##